# getting int value from enum in java

Tags: java

I have enum

```
enum Number{
  FIRST(123),
  SECOND(321);
}

Number nr=Number.FIRST
```

How can I get an enum value (not a String but int ) from my variable nr without creating a new method?

Comment: So, are you trying to get the index (`0`) or the number you have next to `FIRST` in the declaration (`123`)?

Comment: That `enum` won't compile. You need a constructor that takes an `int`. And you will need to create a method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, enums are objects too.  Provide a constructor for your numbers to be passed in, plus a public instance variable; no getter method necessary.

```
enum Num{
  FIRST(123),
  SECOND(321);
  public final int value;
  private Num(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, your integer is mutable here

Comment: Sure, but the OP did state "without creating a new method".

Comment: Eh, you can make it immutable without making it private. Fixed it for you.

Comment: Also, +1 for the best (typically terrible) solution!

Comment: Note, the `private` modifier for the enum constructor is redundant, it is private by definition

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: You can't.

Long version:

The code snippet you have above will not compile because you are missing the constructor:

```
private int value;

public Number(int i) {
    this.value = i;
}
```

After you've done that, then you will need to provide the getter for `value`:

```
public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}
```

EDIT: If you really, really, don't want to create a new method, you can make the `value` field `public`, but you're violating the OO concept of encapsulation (ie, best practice).

Comment: What name conflict? Java doesn't care if you name your class the same as another Class, so long as the fully qualified name is different.

Comment: OK, but who on earth will import some.other.package.Number instead of java.lang.Number?

Comment: Well, if your client class is on the same package (ie, `some.other.package`), then `some.other.package.Number` will be used instead of `java.lang.Number` unless you import `java.lang.Number` specifically.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write your enum like this (also, do not call it `Number` please! There is `java.lang.Number`):

```
enum MyNumber
{
    FIRST(123),
    SECOND(321);

    private final int number;

    MyNumber(final int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
```

If you don't want an accessor, remove the getter and make `number` public.